# Memory leaks issue with malloc in C

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc

I am relatively new to `C` and `malloc`. I wrote a `lib` with basic functions that I am filling with new ones as I go and that I am using for other small projects like this one.

I heard about Valgrind and decided to check my program with it but can't quite understand why I have so many `leaks`, I feel like all my `mallocs` are protected with `if (line == NULL)` when using functions using `malloc` themselves.

Could you guys put me back on tracks here ?

```
static char *concator(char *s1, char *s2, size_t len)
{
    char    *line;
    size_t  size;

    if (!s1 || !s2)
        return (NULL);
    size = strlen(s1) + strlen(s2);
    line = (char*)memalloc(sizeof(char) * size + 1);
    if (line == NULL)
        return (NULL);
    strcpy(line, s1);
    strncat(line, s2, len);
    strdel(&s1);
    return (line);
}

int line_reader(const int fd, char **line)
{
    static char buf[BUFF_SIZE];
    char        *pos;
    int         ret;

    if (fd < 0 || !line || read(fd, buf, 0) < 0 || BUFF_SIZE < 1)
        return (-1);
    *line = strnew(0);
    if (line == NULL)
        return (-1);
    while (1)
    {
        pos = strchr(buf, '\n');
        if (pos)
        {
            *line = concator(*line, buf, pos - buf);
            if (line == NULL)
                return (-1);
            strncpy(buf, &buf[pos - buf + 1], BUFF_SIZE - (pos - buf));
            return (1);
        }
        *line = concator(*line, buf, BUFF_SIZE);
        if (line == NULL)
            return (-1);
        ret = read(fd, buf, BUFF_SIZE);
        buf[ret] = '\0';
        if (!ret)
            return ((**line) ? 1 : 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where in your code are you `free`ing the memory you've allocated?

Comment: What Valgrind is probably telling you (include its report here) is that you don't free the memory you allocate before the program terminates.

Comment: @ChrisTurner How can I `free` what I need to `return`?

Comment: You would free it after you're done using it, not when you return it.

Comment: you're not using `realloc` to expand the size of `*line` - you keep allocating new blocks of memory for it and losing track of the old ones.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `strncpy(buf, &buf[pos - buf + 1], BUFF_SIZE - (pos - buf));` is UB (overlapping source/target buffers).

Comment: @melpomene How can I be sure?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Could you give me some hints about where that'd be located in my code?

Comment: After the return.  You said it yourself: you can't return it if you free it first.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I thought nothing was done after `return`.

Comment: Well, you do *something* with the returned value, don't you?  Otherwise, what's the point of returning it?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Absolutely yes

Comment: OK.  So when you're done with it, `free` it.

Comment: It sounds like the confusion is about when you would free it. It certainly wouldn't be before you return the variable. It would be in some other function that uses that variable. When you malloc data inside a function and return it, it becomes the responsibility of whoever called that function to free the data.

Comment: @Wizzardzz I don't know, it's your code. Do the source/target parts overlap or not?

Comment: Note: `|| BUFF_SIZE < 1` serves no purpose after `read(fd, buf, 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

Free `line` after you're done using it, like:

```
char* line;
int rc = line_reader(fd, &line);
if(rc > 0)
{
    //use line
    printf("%s\n", line);
    //then free it
    free(line);
}
```

This should fix the memory leak problems reported by valgrind. However watch out for other errors mentioned in the comments.